# JavaScript Global Var Hoisting Issue

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Here is my basic issue...

```
<script>
    var window.my_Global = false;
</script>

<script>
    if(my_Global){...} //my_Global here is undefined, not false??
</script>
```

I know there must be a simple solution but I'm pretty stuck...

Comment: The simple solution is to avoid such constructs whenever possible, which is almost always ?

Comment: @adeneo: Since the OP is _explicitly_ asking how to create a global, I'm sure he's aware of the consequences.

Comment: The first script should give an error that would display in the browser's dev tools console.

Comment: So I have changed it as you said... When I alert out the variable from firebug console it says it is still undefined, not false.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Since the OP doesn't know that just doing `my_Global = false` would implcitly create a global in that context, I thought it somewhat important to mention that it should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `var`:

```
window.my_Global = false;
```

You don't need the `var` statement to set properties of an object. In fact, that's invalid syntax:

```html
<script>
    window.my_Global = true;
</script>

<script>
    console.log(my_Global);
    if(my_Global){
        alert("Hello world!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not that you don't need `var` in the sense of it being optional. It's a syntax error.

Comment: So I have changed it as you said... When I alert out the variable from firebug console it says it is still undefined, not false.

Comment: @BradMash — When I alert it out, it is false: http://jsbin.com/xaqagubavu/1/edit?html,output (are you sure you aren't looking at the *return value* of `console.log`?)

Comment: I get that I don't need var, and that it is in fact a syntax error. Additionally I am sure I am looking at the return value... Even if I wasn't, the alert should say false, not undefined.

Comment: Is the console in the same scope? Can you try `window.my_Global`?

Comment: To my understanding it is, results:

console.log(my_Global); //ReferenceError: my_Global is not defined

console.log(window.my_Global); // undefined

Comment: Actually I am incorrect I believe... These scripts live inside an iframe on the page... so when I do window.whatever or even just whatever... it is not going to see the iframe vars.

Comment: Wow this is just craziness... so here is what I believe is the issue... the first script is inside the window... while the second script is nested inside of an iframe... It is all within the same domain, so if I wanted to reference the my_global in the iframe script I would need to do window.parent.my_Global?

Comment: Yea, the iframe will create an isolated scope.

Comment: So, @BradMash, does this answer your question?